# How can I see the rowcounts for tables in a log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

The LogManagement schema shows many tables - which often turn out to be empty when I query them.

[image]

How can I identify which of these tables contain data without having to query each one individually?

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns table names and row counts for all tables with at least one row for the time range selected.

```
union withsource=sourceTable *
| project sourceTable
| summarize count() by sourceTable
```